# What would be the regex expression if I wanted to tokenize a string by spaces, -, ', and " in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

The following code:

```
string = "Hello, I am 5'8\" tall - wow"
regex = re.compile(r'<<regex expression goes here>>')
tokenized_string = regex.split(string)
print tokenized_string
```

Should print:

```
['Hello', 'I', 'am', '5', "'", '8', '"', 'tall', '-', 'wow']
```

So it should ignore spaces, commas, etc., but tokenize `'-'`, `"'"`, and `'"'`.

What would be the correct regex to get this done?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this isn't a regex-writing service

Comment: I've never written a regex in practice before and I couldn't find a clear guide online. I just wanted to see an example.

Comment: Nevertheless, that's not what this site is for. Please read the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) before posting.

Comment: I have read it before and my question is valid.

Comment: No, you are incorrect. *"What should go in this gap in my code?"* is not a valid question without demonstrating some minimal effort to actually implement it (see e.g. [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215694)). There are many Python and general regex resources on the internet, I literally do not believe that you *"couldn't find a clear guide online"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) instead of `re.split`?

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Hello, I am 5'8\" tall - wow"
>>> re.findall(r'''\w+|[-'"]''', s)
['Hello', 'I', 'am', '5', "'", '8', '"', 'tall', '-', 'wow']
```

Above pattern matches word characters (`\w+`) or `-`, `'`, `"`.

NOTE: word character (`\w`) matches alphabets, digits, **and `_`**. If you want to exclude `_`, use `[A-Za-z0-9]` instead of `\w`.

Comment: Any reason I should be using " and not '?

Comment: Also, thanks! So what this regex does is scan the string until it sees something that's NOT an alphanumeric (or _) character OR ', ', and ", which mean it then tokenizes whatever was before and keeps scanning until it finds it again, correct? So if I wrote '''\w+|[-'",]''' it would also skip commas, correct?

Comment: @Michi, You can also use `"""` instead of `'''`

Comment: @Michi, If you use `[-'",]`, `,` also be included in the result.

Comment: Ah, okay. So in Python different sorts of quotes basically help the user distinguish what parts they want grouped together, yes? Is there some convention that's normally followed?

I think I have a better understanding of how to write a regex in Python now. Thanks!

Comment: @Michi, I mean : `"[\"]"` can be expressed `'["]'` or `'''["]'''`, `"""["]"""` (no escaping required if you use different quote).